# database for catalytic reaction mechanism

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis, databases

I am looking for a database containing detailed reaction mechanisms for (homogenous) catalytic reactions. Regular organic textbooks or papers generally draw some broad picture of how the mechanism may work, but generally, they skip many steps.

Is there any collection of detailed mechanisms?
I am primarily interested in catalytic reactions.

For clarification:

- I am primarily looking for homogenous, metal-catalyzed, non-enzymatic reactions of small molecules.
- Searching so far in places like Reaxys or SciFinder did not really result in much more than the bibliography.

Comment: Have you explored Reaxys or SciFinder?

Comment: To answer this question would require pages of text, because there are several types of catalysts. Some are homogeneous, some are heterogeneous. It may be a surface effect, or a cavity effect, or a geometric effect with enzymes, A whole lecture would be needed to answer your question. Sorry ! We cannot develop this chapter here.

Comment: @Maurice It is funny because I know extensive and legitimate databases for synthetic methods, crystallographic structures, proteins structures, small molecule biological activities, etc in spite of the fact that most of those topics "need a whole lecture".